# clearing browser cache in django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a website that I developed using Django. Sometimes I have to change some small css styles or add some new things to the website but every time I need to clear the browser cache by pressing ctrl+f5.
obviously, I cant tell everyone else to clear their browser cache every time they want to use the website.
what should I do to make the app forcingly clear the cache for everyone? thanks for your responses